# Как отправить файл (выбранную таблицу) на печать с сайта с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, печать

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно с помощью языка PHP (или любого другого) вывести нужный файл или выбранную таблицу на сайте в печать на компьютере. По умолчанию есть сведения на моем сайте, которые я хочу выбрать из других и впоследствии распечатать их. То есть отправить файлы на принтер для печати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью javascript.

```
window.print()
```

Если Вам интересует печать только части страницы, то для этого есть [CSS [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media). Там скрываем ненужное для принтера.

По [ссылке](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/36101-kak-vyvodit-na-pechat-soderzhimoe-nuzhnogo-div.html) есть ответ про часть страницы на печать через javacript.